# VS Code can't use copy/paste

Tags: visual-studio-code, iframe, webview, copy, paste

vscode plug-in cannot use copy and paste to embed iframe in webView

Because the plug-in is developed locally, it will be more difficult for other students to install updates.
So I want to embed a react page in an iframe with some input behaviors

Answer (score 0):

Load React App in WebView:

In your VS Code plugin, create a WebView to load the React app. You can use the vscode.WebviewPanel API to create a panel and load HTML content.

```
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
'yourWebviewId',
'Your WebView Title',
 vscode.ViewColumn.One,
 {
   enableScripts: true // Enable JavaScript in the WebView
 }
 );

 const webViewContent = `
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>Your React App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="root"></div>
       <script src="your-react-app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
 `;
```

// Set the HTML content of the WebView
panel.webview.html = webViewContent;